# Remove all keys from an associative array in order to get a simple no key all-value array

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the sort of array I have for instance:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [id] => 21 )
        [1] => Array ( [id] => 24 ) 
      )
```

and I simply want to have

```
Array(21,24)
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: If you have PHP5.5+ you can use array_column. http://php.net/array_column

Comment: How many nested levels can your array have?

Comment: Only 1 nested array like in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($array as &$element){ $element = $element['id']; }
```